# How to download an excel file from OneDrive (teams) using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an excel file on OneDrive (teams). I want to import the data from the excel file into SQL table. Which SSIS task can I use for this?

Here is what I have tried (https://www.techbrothersit.com/2016/07/how-to-download-file-from-sharepoint-by.html)

1. In Onedrive (teams), Share the file with everyone, copy link
2. In visual studio, create a new SSIS projects, Create new connection (HTTP) - this creates the **HTTP connection manager**
3. In the new http connection give the server url as the link copied from step 1
4. Click on test connection - error: The remote server returned an error: `(403) Forbidden`. Even if I enter my credentials then also I get the same error.

If I paste the link in web browser (incognito mode), then it opens the excel file in browser.

I also tried the **OData connection manager**, same error.

Other references (same error):

https://medium.com/@smitagudale712/download-excel-file-from-online-in-ssis-a830c32389f5

https://sqlis.com/Downloading-a-file-over-HTTP-the-SSIS-way/

Comment: script... var wc = new WebClient(); wc.DownloadFile(url, [location to download]);

Comment: @KeithL - I tried this - error: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Net.WebClient.dll: 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'`

Comment: you probably need credentials

Comment: wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(uName, pword);

Comment: that goes between initialization and the download

Comment: Same error `The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.`

Comment: Can you specify what kind of OneDrive this is? Is it a company one? Do you need to log in with username / password to access the file? And what do you mean by "Share with everyone"? Is it everyone inside the company or can you just provide a link for everyone on the internet to have access?

Comment: 1. OneDrive integration for Microsoft teams; 2. Assume log-in is not required; 3. "Share with everyone" on the internet with the link